# Flink TimescaleDB Integration

Tags: apache-flink, timescaledb

How to integrate Apache Flink with Timescale Db.Explain How integration is done along with some example codes.The problem is Kafka writes into a topic flink reads it and after some calculation it should write in Timescale Db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use Flink's Table API with the [JDBC connector](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/connect.html#jdbc-connector) with the PostgreSQL driver to write to TimescaleDB. If you get stuck trying to make that work, ask a more specific question, showing what you've tried and explain what's going wrong.

Comment: can u give me some example code??because i am beginner in flink and i dont know where to start in db integration.